# msbuild using Yui.Compressor fails

Tags: .net-4.0, msbuild, visual-studio-2012, yui-compressor

Im trying to use msbuild to compress my js and css files using yui.compressor.net.

Tried the sample at http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/, but i can't get it to run.

Im getting :

> D:\Inetpub\SitecoreDev 2012\Website\MSBuild\Deploy.xml(63,5): error MSB4062: The "CompressorTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly D:\Inetpub\SitecoreDev 2012\Website\MSBuild\Yahoo.Yui.Comp
>   ressor.Build.MsBuild.dll. Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.CompressorTask.Execute()'. Security accessibility of the overriding method m
>   ust match the security accessibility of the method being overriden. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task co
>   ntains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Im trying to use msbuild on a VS2012, on Windows 8 rc.